# Is "completed Bachelor" a correct and natural sounding expression in English?

Tags: phrase-request

I am searching for a shorter way to refer to a Bachelor I have completed and obtained a degree or to a Bachelor I have not completed.

I thought about writing "completed/uncompleted Bachelor", or maybe "finished/unfinished Bachelor". But the dictionary doesn't list "completed" as a possible adjective and both ways, "finished" and "completed", don't sound natural to me when applied to a Bachelor.

*Question*: Is it OK to say "completed/uncompleted Bachelor" (or maybe "finished/unfinished") or is there a better expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of degrees, an unfinished degree is nothing at all. Usually you would not mention it. A completed bachelor's degree is a bachelor's degree. It doesn't need qualification.

Here are a couple of examples

On an application form, you have to account for all the time after you left school:

> 2011-2012 Studying for a Computer Science degree (not completed)
>   2012-2015 Studying for a Psychology degree.

And in the section about qualifications don't mention the Computer science degree at all. Since you don't have any kind of degree in computer science.

> 2015 BSc Psychology

In an interview:

> *Do you have any experience with programming?*
>
> Yes, I actually started a computer science degree but switched to Psychology after one year. We had learned about algorithm design and the Java programming language.
>
> *Why did you switch?*
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My doubt was related exactly to the admissions process requirement of informing all of my post-secondary academic work. Sometimes, though, I want to be able to refer to my ("not completed"?) undergrad course in the least ammount of words possible. In my native tongue, one can simply talk about his "unfinished Bachelor" or "unfinished undergrad course". But it seems that there is no similar expression in English?

Answer (score 0):

Being an *undergraduate* typically means that you are working towards a bachelor degree, as in still studying or working towards the completion of the degree. Once the degree is achieved people usually just say that they have a Bachelor in whatever they studied in. I don't typically hear completed/uncompleted or finished/unfinished in conversation and on resumes usually would indicate in the process of obtaining a Bachelor in whatever or would say Bachelor in whatever and the date achieved

Comment: Thanks! I ask this because I have a Bachelor degree but also have an unfinished(?) Bachelor, that I simply dropped out and don't intend to finish

Comment: So in conversation you could say that you have one Bachelor degree and began and dropped out of another undergraduate degree. As for resumés I found a resource that may be useful on the edict for including unfinished programs on resumés (if you need it!) https://www.workitdaily.com/incomplete-degree-resume/

Comment: I definitely need it!:) Thank you! But is there no shorter way to refer to this? Do I really need all the verbosity? And I hope you don't mind a quick unrelated question, but if I have a Master degree, what does "previous graduate" work mean? Does it mean only the work related to the Master or also the work of the Bachelor degree? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can say, *"I have **completed** my Bachelor's degree in X,"* but it's more common to say, *"I **have** a Bachelor's degree in X."*

Comment: @Andrew thank you! And how would you formally mention a Bachelor that one has dropped out and has no intention of finishing?

Comment: @flen  If you dropped out of school then I would not mention it, since it's not a positive.  If you have to talk about it, then it depends on what you want to say.  For example, *"I started my Bachelor's degree in X but unfortunately I could not finish due to extenuating circumstances"*  On the other hand, if you moved from one program to another (which you finished) then you say, *"I started university with a major in X but after a year I changed to Y."*  In the US, at least, changing majors is not unusual.